# Play video from localhost with HTML5 with php

Tags: php, html

Hello all i have problem when playing video locally from localhost. I use html5, i put my video on localhost/myProject/vide. Can you help me ? why i access it with HTML 5

Comment: i access http://localhost/myProject
i put my video in lampp/htdocs/myProject/video

how can i access video from localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need php, just HTML for this.

```
<video width="WWW" height="HHH" controls="controls">
  <source src="file:///c:/path/to/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="file:///c:/path/to/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but the video can't play. I put the html file and video in localhost

Comment: I'm recommending using file://, not http[colon]//localhost

what server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1- in **vide** folder create new file like ***video.php***

2- inside ***vide*** folder copy a file name ***video.mp4*** just for test which is video file

now update ***video.php*** which is located in vide folder

```
<video src="video.mp4" controls>
<p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. Here is a 
     <a href="video.mp4">link to the video</a> instead.</p>
```

now access : http://localhost/myProject/vide/video.php